# Error connection APNS server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I've an app with push notification service enabled until now without problems. But yesterday I did a mistake, revoked a certificate and the notifications doesn't work.
Then I created a new apns push production certificate (.p12 file) and I put into my server. But now I've the following error:

> System.IO.IOException : Authentication failed because the remote side closed the transport stream .

Reading in forums I noticed that ssl3 security is not supported and then I tried to change to tls. But when I tried this I have this error:

> the remote side closed the transport stream

I've tried to generate .p12 files with private keys with 2048bits RSA without results.

This mi server code. I'm using MoonApns.

```
certificate = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(p12FilePassword), New X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(P12File)), New X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(P12File), p12FilePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet))
    _certificates = New X509Certificate2Collection()
    _certificates.Add(_certificate)

    Dim _apnsClient As TcpClientapnsClient = New TcpClient()
    _apnsClient.Connect(ProductionHost, NotificationPort)

    Dim _apnsStream As SslStream = New SslStream(_apnsClient.GetStream(), False, AddressOf validateServerCertificate, AddressOf SelectLocalCertificate)

    Try

        _apnsStream.AuthenticateAsClient(ProductionHost, _certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, False)

Catch ex As System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
            Throw ex
        End Try
```

Thanks for you help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my own solution!

If you use Moon APNS with .p12 certificate and you need to use tls security, you have to install the apns_production.cer in your apns server. If you don't have this you probably will have a socket exception in your system.

Thanks